# How to print "\n" stored in variable in TCL

Tags: shell, tcl

I have a variable that is set by the user, lets say a is "/n/nhelloworld" I don't want "\n" to create a new line but instead for it to be printed.

Basically for an output of the variable value without the formatting, just the raw text.

Because it is stored in the variable and set by the user I can't use {} instead of "", or at least I tried and it didn't work

Comment: Did you mean to say `lets say a is "\n\nhelloworld"`?

Answer (score 3):

You can just escape the backslash, as in:

```
set a "\n\nhelloworld"
set b [string map {"\n" "\\n"} $a]
```

and then just print $b

Comment: this is just an example, if as you say $<var> already eq "\n\nhelloworld" set by another user, it still works the same way of course

Comment: Also remember that you can many things at once in the same `string map` call. That simplifies things like converting newline to `\n` and backslash to \\ at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If the literal character sequence `\n` is in a variable, that's what will print out with `puts` - no substitutions are performed while outputting the value.  Backslash substitutions (which is what turns the 2 character sequence `\n` to the codepoint 10: linefeed) only happens when parsing literal values in Tcl script; by the `subst` command unless `-nobackslashes` is given, and by the `expr` command in quoted strings (or other commands that treat their arguments as expressions: `if`, `while`, `for`, etc).

```
set msg [format hello%cnworld 0x5C]   ;# codepoint 0x5C is backslash
puts $msg                             ;# prints "hello\nworld"

# Show the hex values of all the bytes of the UTF-8 string
# to prove that the sequence "\n" (0x5C 0x6E) is in the value
puts [regexp -all -inline .. [binary encode hex [encoding convertto utf-8 $msg]]]
```

If you're receiving a string from the user containing the sequence `\n` but that is showing as a newline you almost certainly have a remote code execution vulnerability (caused by a user-submitted value going through a parse and substitution phase, which can include script substitution - any code the user supplies will be run).  Check for expressions that aren't brace quoted, `eval`s etc.